# How can i define classpath directory in Equinox?

Tags: java, classpath, osgi, bundle, equinox

is there a way to define a directory as classpath per bundle in Eclipse Equinox? So that i can put all 3rd party jars/configuration files per bundle into this directory. I know that this can be done by defining each jar separately but i need an easier way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No. Each bundle has its own classpath that must be entirely contained within it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of the [target platform](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Ftarget.htm)? It's a shared pool of bundles which are eligible to be included on the 'OSGi classpath' of any bundle which imports suitable packages. You can include individual bundles and whole folders inside the target platform.

Under normal circumstances I'd avoid embedding too many third party jars inside your OSGi bundles (ie directly on the bundle classpath) since it's cleaner to share common instances between bundles.